# Is there any way to check in items or create a new project from files via the API?

Tags: azure-devops

We're starting to automate some of our project kickoff processes.  We already have a project management app (built in-house) that creates the base Solution and C# project with some default screens, authentication, etc. and populates some standard data like App Name and Namespace.

Ideally, what I'd like to wind up with is clicking a button in our project management app, having it create a VSTS project for the app, pull the template files and manipulate them as-needed, and check it all in to VSTS as a "ground zero" changeset for that newly created VSTS project.  At that point, our dev team can just connect to the project and pull it down in Visual Studio.

From what I'm seeing in the [REST APIs documentation for VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics), you can get a list of changesets and files associated with a changeset, but I'm not seeing any references on adding or checking in files.

Is this something that can be done via the APIs, or some other automated extension mojo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rest API to [create a new project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#create-a-team-project).

For Version Control, since you mentioned "check in as changeset", I assume you are using TFVC. The Rest API can only get the information about TFVC version control, it cannot check in files for now. If you want to check in files via API, you can consider using [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet). Refer to this link for details: [Team Foundation Version Control client API example for TFS 2010 and newer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/). It works with VSTS too.